# SimpleDateFormat во всей красе

Tags: java, дата

Кто подскажет,почему данный код всегда выдает месяц - январь?

```
BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));

SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("mm/dd/yyyy");
Date date = simpleDateFormat.parse(reader.readLine());
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat1 = new SimpleDateFormat("MMM dd, yyyy", Locale.ENGLISH);
System.out.println(simpleDateFormat1.format(date));
```

Ввод:
5/11/2015

Вывод:
Jan 11, 2015

Comment: Потому что не "mm/dd/yyyy", а "MM/dd/yyyy". Маленькие mm - минуты

Answer (score 1, accepted):

как сказал @cache "mm/dd/yyyy" - минуты дни год, "MM/dd/yyyy" - месяц день год